# how to get data with cheerio? when i see in page source data is empty, but when i see in inspect element i see the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, ecmascript-6, cheerio

i hope you care. I have troble when scraping data in another website. this my case, when i see in page source data is empty, but when i see in inspect element i see the data. if you not understand see these image, first in inspect element and second in view page source

[image]

[image]

**this is my code**

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const url = "https://pikobar.jabarprov.go.id/"

request(url, (error, response, html) => {
   let $ = cheerio.load(html);
   $('b').each((i, element) => {
      let omg = $(element).text();
      console.log(omg);
   });
});
```

this is  my result
[image]

i want text 388

Comment: what you want to get the 388 text ? I really don't understand

Comment: yes, i want 388

Comment: as you can see the 388 text is render in client side and not in server side, when is render by server side you can get the data by see source page option in browser, but if you didn't find in there probably is built in client side, so JS do that job instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the document source (Ctrl+U), this element is really empty. That's because it's being filled afterwards, by a Ajax request. If you go to Network tab and reload, you will see all files being transferred. The url you are looking for is https://covid19-public.digitalservice.id/api/v1/rekapitulasi/jabar?level=prov which have the data you are looking for.

```js
fetch("https://covid19-public.digitalservice.id/api/v1/rekapitulasi/jabar?level=prov")
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(d => console.log(d.data.content.positif))
```